# How to return a custom response for validation errors using Hibernate Validator and Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-validator

I implemented a REST endpoint in my Quarkus application.
For validation purpose I'm using the hibernate-validator. So I added the @Valid annotation to the incoming parameter and added some constraints to that class.
Everythings works as expected.

When sending a request with invalid data I see a response like this:

```
{
   "exception": null,
   "propertyViolations": [],
   "classViolations": [],
   "parameterViolations": [   {
      "constraintType": "PARAMETER",
      "path": "aaa.bbb.Id",
      "message": "Id does not match the expected format.",
      "value": "abc"
   }],
   "returnValueViolations": []
}
```

But I would like to have a more compact response and maybe add some additional information:

```
{
   "additional-info": "some text",
   "path": "aaa.bbb.Id",
   "message": "Id does not match the expected format.",
}
```

I found the same question for hibernate-validator and spring-boot: [How to return a custom response pojo when request body fails validations that are defined using Bean Validation/Hibernate Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571687/how-to-return-a-custom-response-pojo-when-request-body-fails-validations-that-ar)
But I do not know how to adapt the solutions to Quarkus.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to provide an implementation of `ExceptionMapper<ValidationException>`.

Something like:

```
@Provider
public class ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
         // convert the exception into a response
         // see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.13.3.Final/extensions/hibernate-validator/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/validator/runtime/jaxrs/ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper.java#L32 for inspiration
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I'm looking for. I already tried to use an ExceptionMapper but did not know which exception to map (ValidationException). How did you figured that out? (How can I find this out for myself next time?)

Comment: I wrote the code :). 

More seriously, the absolute best way to figure things out is to have a copy of the source code and use a debugger

Comment: It's worth noting that simply implementing `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` will not cover ValidationException, but will cover other Throwable subclasses. Maybe this is a hardcoded special case?

Comment: @IvanG., no that's how the JAX-RS spec works, i.e. a mapper of more specific type of exception is selected over a mapper of a more general type.

Comment: @geoand makes sense, thanks! So that implies Quarkus ships with a specific `ExceptionMapper<ValidationException>`

Comment: Exactly. You can see the included ones at http://localhost:8080/q/dev-ui/io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-reactive/exception-mappers